# How to get access token via rest template call for docusign in springboot app?

Tags: oauth, jwt, docusignapi

I am new to the Docusign integration in springboot gradle application. I am trying to get access token in spring boot app using Rest template but there is no way we do that as per their docs and all. We can only get access token by generating URI using integration key and other things and the we have to copy that uri and paste it to the browser to get code token which we can use to then get JWT access token through API call.

Can we not create JWT access token through rest API calls in application only, please I need all your here...

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: I'm having the same issue, and the answer below doesn't seem to help because there is still a one-time consent, and when you start up your server is when it would be required to consent, but you can't because there is no user, no browser, nothing just the Spring Boot server startup. So there doesn't seem to be any solution. I even checked directly on their website to see if in my profile I could set something that would be automatic consent. Also @Sunit Kale, how did you configure your Spring Boot to work with Docusign including the POM files? thanks.

Comment: Hi @bytor99999, I am done with the DocuSign integration and created blog for future reference you can look into that if you have any questions you can ask here: https://sunitkale.medium.com/springboot-docusign-integration-using-library-961801dc23d7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Auth Code Grant](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/authcode/) requires a browser and user interaction (log in)

[JWT authentication](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/) does not and you can use this to have your app generate an access token without the user having to open a browser.

However, a one-time [consent is required](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/consent/obtaining-individual-consent/) for JWT as well and you can do that manually once and no need to worry about this again.

I would strongly suggest to use the [Java quickstart](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/), because not only it gives you working code, it configures everything for you automatically.